# Connect from linux terminal to mongodb in Monghq (compose.io)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, mongodb, mongohq

I'm triying to connect from my linux terminal (Linux Mint 17) to a remote mongodb database in mongohq. I try using this command:

```
mongo arrow.mongohq.com:port/cac-test –u userhere -p passwordhere
```

But isn't work. I just got this message: `connecting to: arrow.mongohq.com:27043/database-name-here
loading file: –u
2015-05-07T10:27:57.645-0600 file [–u] doesn't exist
failed to load: –u`

I don't know what is the problem. I read in other places but I can't figure it out.

Maybe someone can help me, if exist any procedure to connect, some other commands or configurations.

Thanks.